# Flexbox grid with multi-width columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a 4 column flexbox grid that is used to display products. All products have a width of 25% but how can I ensure the grid doesn't break if just 1 product gets a width of 75% for example so that I can display 2 products on one row?

Is there a way, using flexbox, to give the wider 75% grid item priority so that it automatically adjusts/shifts the grid to ensure it doesn't break like it does at the moment?

**jsFiddle** *(Code at the bottom)*

https://jsfiddle.net/kdjkc15g/

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

**CSS**

```
.grid-uniform {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.grid__item {
  width: 25%;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: $gutter*2;
}

.grid__item.featured-product {
  width: 75%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-grid">
 <div class="grid-uniform">
  <a href="#" class="product grid__item">
    <div class="flex-content">
      <div class="grid__image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
      </div>
      <div class="grid product-info">
      <p>
      This is a title
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your CSS to this. It's fully responsive now.

**The CSS**

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.flex-grid {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-uniform {
  display: flex; display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid__item {
  flex-grow: 1; -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.grid__item.featured-product {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.grid__image {
  background:#f4f4f4;
  padding-top:$gutter;
  padding-bottom:$gutter;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdjkc15g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

A rather easy way to do that type of layout is through CSS Grid module. But since you've asked it for Flexbox; here is my take:

The flexbox-based grid here is required to be adjusted on width (not exactly the `width` property, but `flex-basis`). Using `flex-basis` makes it more easier to size up the flexbox-children, therefore I avoided giving them a `width`.

The adjustment I made below is with `calc()`, substracting the `(n-1)` times of the gutter width from each `.grid__item`.

**Why (n-1) times?**

We've been giving a left margin to each of the `.grid__item` and want it not to collapse. So, we discount the last cell in a row.

```css
/* Box-sizing reset */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-grid {
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.grid-uniform {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.grid__item {
  display: flex;
  /* Used `flex` instead of `width` */
  flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 60px); /* (4-1) * 20px = 60px
  /* Used `margin` instead of `padding` */
  margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* Gave it a size in order to make it look "uniform" */
  max-height: 350px;
}

.grid__item.featured-product {
  flex-basis: calc(75% - 60px); /* (4-1) * 20px = 60px */
}

.flex-content {
  /* Made the content take up the whole available width and hide bleed-outs, if any */
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid__image img {
  /* Made the dummy images look okay */
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="grid-uniform">
    <a href="#" class="product grid__item">
      <div class="flex-content">
        <div class="grid__image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
        </div>
        <div class="grid product-info">
          <p>
            This is a title
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product grid__item">
      <div class="flex-content">
        <div class="grid__image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
        </div>
        <div class="grid product-info">
          <p>
            This is a title
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product grid__item">
      <div class="flex-content">
        <div class="grid__image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
        </div>
        <div class="grid product-info">
          <p>
            This is a title
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product grid__item">
      <div class="flex-content">
        <div class="grid__image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
        </div>
        <div class="grid product-info">
          <p>
            This is a title
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product grid__item">
      <div class="flex-content">
        <div class="grid__image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
        </div>
        <div class="grid product-info">
          <p>
            This is a title
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product grid__item featured-product">
      <div class="flex-content">
        <div class="grid__image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/550x350">
        </div>
        <div class="grid product-info">
          <p>
            This is a title
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product grid__item">
      <div class="flex-content">
        <div class="grid__image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
        </div>
        <div class="grid product-info">
          <p>
            This is a title
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product grid__item">
      <div class="flex-content">
        <div class="grid__image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
        </div>
        <div class="grid product-info">
          <p>
            This is a title
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it was helpful. Cheers!